# Hide/move the Particle Effect panel on the Scene view window

Tags: unity

[image: Particle System]

The problem for example is if I want to drag the particle system object to the bottom-right corner of my view, then it goes behind the Particle Effect panel.

Is there any way to do hide or move this panel in editor mode and/or in runtime mode?

[image: Empty gameobject as parent]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I just created new empty GameObject dragged the object with the particle system to be child of it and now I can drag it around just dragging the empty GameObject.

[image: Empty GameObject and the Particle system is child of it]